# Need to interface to a C++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I need to call a C++ API from C#. I have been able to call the API, but the char[] parameters do not seem to be marshalling correctly.
Here's the C++ signature:

```
Create2ptModel(double modelPowers[2], 
               double modelDacs[2], 
               int pclRange[2],
               double targetPowers[32], 
               double *dacAdjustFactor,
               unsigned short powerRampFactors[32], 
               BOOL bPCLDacAdjusted[32],
               char calibrationModel[32],
               char errMsg[1024])
```

and this is how I am trying to call it from C#

```
[DllImport("AlgorithmsLib.dll", EntryPoint = "_Create2ptModel@36", 
 ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, 
 CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern AlgorithmStatus Create2ptModel(
    double[] modelPowers, 
    double[] modelDacs, 
    int[] pclRange, 
    double[] targetPowers, 
    ref double dacAdjustFactor, 
    ushort[] powerRampFactors, 
    bool[] bPCLDacAdjusted, 
    /**/char[] calibrationModel, 
    char[] errMsg/**/);
```

Any idea of how I can marshall it correctly?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the two asterisks to the left of calibrationModel in the C# a typo?

Comment: I think he was trying to highlight them. I have formatted the code.

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't use `CharSet.Auto` you know the character set of the lib, use that. If you let the machinery guess, it could guess wrongly.
2. Are those `char[]` parameters null terminated? Are they inputs or outputs? If they are null-terminated inputs, then just use `string` instead of `char[]`.

Comment: This is correct.  CharSet.Ansi is required, the char[] must be string.